# Rotating and translating display lists

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using wglUseFontBitmaps() to create display lists of a font and then glListBase, glCallLists to display some text in OpenGL.
But the glRotate() and glTranslate() functions don't affect the text's position.
How can I rotate the text or change its position?

Comment: Make sure you don't load an identity matrix or something inside your display list.

Comment: I am using only glRasterPos() to set the initial position

Comment: You might want to try rastering your text to an offscreen texture, and then positioning that texture any way you want. This is a little involved though and it might take a significant effort to set up if you're new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't transform OpenGL bitmaps. Period. The only thing you can move around, affected by the transformation pipeline, is the starting position set using `glRasterPos`.

`glRasterPos` effectively sends sort of a "vertex" that gets transformed by the modelview and projection, however the effecting viewport position is just the start position of the following bitmap drawing.

Comment: Used wglUseFontOutlines() instead of wglUseFontBitmaps() and now I am able to scale and rotate the text, but now with an orthographic matrix it is mirrored. How can I solve that?

Comment: @slaviber: Probably you've flipped the `bottom` and `top` parameters of `gl[u]Ortho[2D]`. Either exchange those two, or add a -1 scale in the y direction on the modelview matrix you draw your text with (`glScalef(1,-1,1); draw_text();`)